# Generic Handler - Parser Error, Could not create type

Tags: c#, iis, asp

Seguinte pessoal, fiz um Generic Handler simples, só pra me devolver uma pessoa, só pra constar, o código está dessa maneira

```
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.Cache.SetNoStore(); 
        context.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        context.Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;

        Pessoa p;
        p = new Pessoa();
        p.Nome = "Enzo";
        p.SobreNome = "Tiezzi";
        p.Idade = 19;
        //"{"Nome":"Enzo","SobreNome":"Tiezzi","Idade":19}"
        String json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(p);
        context.Response.Write(json);
        context.Response.StatusCode = 200;
    }
```

No meu servidor local(IIS) ele funciona normalmente, mas quando coloco em um servidor online ele me traz o seguinte erro ao acessar o `.ashx` diretamente:
[image: Parser Error]

Comment: Cara, já tive muitos problemas com Publish do Visual Studio. Publicava meu projeto e quando jogava no IIS não funcionava e no meu IIS Express(Visual Studio) funcionava. Comecei a fazer pesquisa e percebi que o Publish não contemplava todos os arquivos necessários, principalmente com Report Service e outros. Não estou dizendo que seja isso, mas sempre é bom dar uma conferida e verificar se todos os arquivos necessários estão no seu servidor.